# How to copy files from the linux to windows with rcp

Tags: linux, rcp

I want to remote copy the file from linux to windows with rcp. While the rcp cmd don't support the "c:". How can I rcp to the c:\

```
rcp /home/CommonFuncs.pm windows2003:C:/CommonFuncs.pm
Winsock RSHD/NT: Error 3 executing '/usr/lib/sunw,rcp -tZ C:/CommonFuncs.pm' The system cannot find the path specified.

rcp /home/CommonFuncs.pm windows2003:C:/CommonFuncs.pm
Winsock RSHD/NT: Error 3 executing '/usr/lib/sunw,rcp -tZ C\:/CommonFuncs.pm' The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Comment: Wouldn't `smbclient` be a better suited tool for this task?

Answer (score 2):

Rather try using `scp` command like below

```
scp /home/CommonFuncs.pm user@hostname:C:\CommonFuncs.pm
```

Comment: The failure of the rcp is the destination 'windows2003:C:\CommonFuncs.pm'. From the man, the c: is not allow.

Comment: Rcp copies files between machines.  Each file or directory argument is either a remote file name of the form ''rhost:path'', or a local file name (containing no ':' characters, or a  '/'  before  any ':'s).

Comment: @firelyu, didn't check MAN pages but check with the similar SCP command in my answer. that will do the work. RCP one is kinda hunch.

Comment: @firelyu, then shouldn't you be accepting the answer probably with a +1 to show your appreciation.